# Error correction: should it be "farmers" or "farming"?

Tags: exam-questions

This is from an exam question:

> The main problem concerning **farming** is that the income earned by farmers is not adequate to meet their consumption needs.

Is the *farming* used here correct? Concerning means worrying, causing anxiety so isn't it better to use *farmers* instead of *farming*?

Also can the *consumption* be omitted from the sentence?

Comment: No, because "concerning farming" could just be a shortened version of "concerning the farming industry". Is there sufficient context to know that "their consumption needs" = "their needs"?

Comment: When you say "Error Correction", is someone saying that the example contains an error? If so, you should say so in your question.

Comment: @user3169 I am saying error correction because they are from an error correction exercise, I have used exam question tag.

Comment: @user212388 Is the error supposed to be on expression or comprehension? The sentence you give, as it stands, is correct. But if it is included in a comprehension exercise then, of course, it should be compared to the comprehension text.

Answer (score 3):

*Concerning* in this sentence is a preposition, it means "on the subject of", it is synonym of "about":

> The main problem about farming is...

*Concerning* means "worrying" when it is an adjective, for example :

> The situation of small farmers nowadays is very concerning.

So *farming* is the right word to use, you are talking about the industry as a whole and not about the people.

---

Concerning the second part of your question:

> can *the consumption* be omitted from the sentence ?

I would not omit it because the farmers' needs could extend to a lot more besides consumption, "consumption" specifies the sort of needs you are talking about.